# How to update a record in database using NeDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, nedb

I have created a database to store details of people. I have a record like:

```
   {"Name":"moon","Email":"night","User":"sun","Password":"earth","_id":"kpOBxczJlr2R5S68"}
```

How do change the password from 'earth' to 'mars'??
How do I use the db.update() in NeDB to make this change??

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/33590114/6568620 ?

Comment: the official docs https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#updating-documents

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the way explained in the docs work for you? For example:

```
db.update({ _id: 'kpOBxczJlr2R5S68 }, { password: 'mars' }, {}, (err, num) => {
  // ...
});
```

What have you tried so far? Did you try the examples from the documentation?

Comment: I want to add Salary and Company field also. So I wrote it like:
var id= result._id;
result is the object 
 db.update(
           { id}, 
           { $set: { Salary: Salary,Company: Company} },
           {},
           function (err, numReplaced) {
             console.log("replaced---->" + numReplaced);
           }
           );

Is there anything wrong in this?

Comment: @Aarathi.V.B Yes. You're using `{ id }` which is the same as `{ id: id }` and here you should use the key of `_id` as in my example. Did you run that code at all? - On the other hand `{ Salary: Salary, Company: Company }` can be shortened as `{ Salary, Company }`